# Ban command: ReferenceError: message is not defined (Discord.Js)

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

"message is not defined" my code is really bad plz dont judge :(

```
client.on('message', msg => {
if (message.content.startsWith === 'd?ban') {
if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("Invalid Permissions")
let User = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0])
if (!User) return message.channel.send("Invalid User")
if (User.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("Invalid Permissions")
let banReason = args.join(" ").slice(22);
if (!banReason) {
  banReason = "None"

}}})
```

Comment: Hello, it seems like this Question has been answered. Make sure to mark the Answer with the Green tick to finish off the Question.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to check your variable names for consistency. You named the message object in the function as `msg` but you tried accessing it later as `message`.

Try this:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.content.startsWith === 'd?ban') {
if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("Invalid Permissions")
let User = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0])
if (!User) return message.channel.send("Invalid User")
if (User.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("Invalid Permissions")
let banReason = args.join(" ").slice(22);
if (!banReason) {
  banReason = "None"

}}})
```

Comment: Haha, you beat me to answering by just a few secs. I totally agree with this answer.

Comment: Ah sorry, I know how it feels lol. If you have any edits feel free to suggest/make the edit!

Comment:  haha, got it! Thanks for the suggestion too!

Comment: Made some minor improvements to the code, just awaiting approval.